# using solution folder in web config connection string

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-config

I want to put my db inside Solution Items folder. How can use these folder in connection string as data source.?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Solution Items` folder is only a logical folder inside your solution, it has no mapping to folders on disk. So just put your db wherever you want it *on disk* and use that location in connection string.

Comment: If I understand you I cannot use these folder for db storage location ?

Comment: @panjo You can, but it won't affect file location. Why don't you just try it for yourself?

Comment: already tried :) my first question is all about that. Thanks anyway, I will use  App_Data instead.